# data-dismissible in collapsible in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, css, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-mobile

I creating web application in MVC4 with Jquery Mobile. We used Collapsible in JQM as Menu in header. Its works great. But requirement is whenever click is made in any part of window the menu should disappear.  Please guide me. Below is my code.

```
<div class="ui-btn ui-corner-all" data-role="collapsible" data-inset="true" data-icon="user" style="float: right" data-dismissible= "true">
                        <h2>@this.Session["UserId"]</h2>
                        <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="b">
                            <li data-icon="false"><a href="#popupLogin" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop">Language</a></li>
                            <li data-icon="false"> <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Login")">Logout</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Wait wait wait your question is confusing. You use collapsible in JQM as Menu in header, if click is made in any part of window the menu should disappear. Ok that part is understandable. But this sentence "But i have no idea how to bring it in JQM collapsible" doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Gajotres ya tads my mistake i edited the question

Comment: One more question, menu (Collapsible) should dispensary completely of should it just collapse back to previous original state? Or are we talking about popup which is accessible through this menu?

Comment: It just collapse back to previous original state. When user clicked any other place in window after clicking collapse first.

Comment: Wait it should collapse? Or is this your current state?